# Can we always find a point in a metric space where we get equality in the triangle inequality?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose we have a metric space $(X, d)$, and two fixed points $p, q \in X$. Then, can we always find a point $x \in X$ such that 
$d(x, p) = d(x, q) + d(q, p)$? And if so, is this maximum value of of $d(x, p)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: just take $x=q$ and you're done.

Comment: of course; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the real line, use metric $d(x,y) = \sqrt{|x-y|\;}$  Then you have equality $d(a,c) = d(a,b)+d(b,c)$ only if $a=b$ or $b=c$.